# Como fazer um grafico de bolhas com um conjunto de dados com milhões de observações?

Tags: r, ggplot2, big-data

Gostaria de fazer um gráfico de bolhas com o seguinte banco de dados:

```
head(dados)

 orgao   raca sexo uf idade    salario  ano freq

  ANEC BRANCO    M    DF    45 2148.19 1990    1
  UNIR BRANCO    M    AC    46 5653.96 1990    1
  UFOP BRANCO         ES    19 6806.84 1990    1
TROPIGE   PARDO  F    SP    74 8949.78 1990    1
  EARRNET  PARDO      SE    58 8532.42 1990    1
  UFPEL BRANCO   M    MG    33 5450.83 1990    1
```

Utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
ggplot(grafico, aes(x= idade, y=salario)) +
   geom_point(aes(col=raca, size= freq))
```

Mas aparece o seguinte erro:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 38.1 Mb

Não sei como resolver, alguém pode me ajudar?
Obs: não tem como eu inserir os dados manualmente porque a minha base de dados é muito grande, com 10 milhões de linhas.

---

### Dados em formato `dput`

```
dados <-
structure(list(orgao = c("ANEC", "UNIR", "UFOP", "TROPIGE", "EARRNET", 
"UFPEL"), raca = c("BRANCO", "BRANCO", "BRANCO", "PARDO", "PARDO", 
"BRANCO"), sexo = c("M", "M", NA, "F", NA, "M"), uf = c("DF", 
"AC", "ES", "SP", "SE", "MG"), idade = c(45L, 46L, 19L, 74L, 
58L, 33L), salario = c(2148.19, 5653.96, 6806.84, 8949.78, 8532.42, 
5450.83), ano = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L), 
freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Só por curiosidade, quantas linhas há nesse conjunto de dados?

Comment: 10 milhões......

Comment: 38.1 Mb só é problema se tiver muitas outras coisas na sessão R. Uma solução é amostar algumas linhas da base e plotar só essas.

Answer (score 6):

Minha sugestão nesse caso é **não fazer** um gráfico de bolhas. Este tipo de visualização funciona muito bem em conjuntos de dados pequenos, mas a partir de um certo número de observações, fica inviável compreender as relações entre as variáveis. Abaixo mostro um exemplo muito aparecido com o seu, com três variáveis quantitativas e uma categórica, e apenas 1.000 observações:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
n <- 1e3

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n), 
                 y = rnorm(n), 
                 z = runif(n), 
                 cor = sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), n, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = cor, size = z))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Veja que, mesmo com apenas 0.01% da quantidade dos dados presentes no teu problema, a visualização não está boa. Há muita sobreposição entre as bolhas, não permitindo identificar onde estão as maiores ou as menores, ou até mesmo se há clusters formados pelos níveis da variável categórica.

Assumindo que a tua análise está em um estágio exploratório, proponho criar um outro gráfico, que vai te permitir verificar relações entre as variáveis do teu conjunto de dados. Não sei se há um nome em português para este gráfico, mas eu chamo ele de *hexbin*.

O que o gráfico *hexbin* faz é criar uma divisão em hexágonos do plano onde os dados estão plotados. A seguir, ele faz um mapa de calor, identificando quais regiões estão com uma maior concentração de informação. Bem, é melhor mostrar o resultado do que escrever sobre ele:

```r
library(ggplot2)
# nao eh preciso carregar este pacote, mas 
# ele deve estar instalado em seu pc
library(hexbin)

set.seed(1)
n <- 1e7

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n), 
                 y = rnorm(n), 
                 z = runif(n), 
                 cor = sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), n, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_hex(bins = 15) +
  facet_wrap(~ cor)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Ao menos no meu computador pessoal (Intel i5 2.8GHz, com 8GB de RAM) eu consegui criar um gráfico a partir de um data frame com 10 milhões de linhas. Logicamente, há três limitações aqui:

1. É possível colocar a informação de cor em um mesmo gráfico, mas as categorias ficarão sobrepostas. Portanto, preferi separá-las em painéis. Afinal, assumindo novamente que é um estudo na parte exploratória, o importante é visualizar as diferenças e semelhanças entre os níveis dessa variável categórica (`cor`, no meu exemplo, `raca` no teu).
2. A informação sobre o tamanho das bolhas foi ignorada. Novamente, com 10 milhões de linhas, essa é uma informação que não aparecerá bem no gráfico, devido à enorme sobreposição que existe. Por isso, preferi excluí-la da visualização e exibir a densidade dos pontos, de modo a destacar em quais regiões da relação entre as variáveis preditora e resposta estão concentrados mais sujeitos.
3. A criação de um gráfico *hexbin* não era obrigatória. Seria possível colocar essa informação da densidade nos pontos, com um comando tipo `geom_point(alpha = 0.1)`, por exemplo. Novamente, devido a literalmente milhares de sobreposições que podem ocorrer no conjunto de dados original, essa transparência talvez não ficasse óbvia e o *hexbin* consegue lidar melhor com essa quantidade imensa de informação.

Mas, mesmo com essas limitações que listei, acredito que o resultado ficou mais interessante do que se um gráfico de bolhas fosse utilizado no mesmo contexto.

Comment: Uma sugestão: passar a coluna *z* para a `aes`, de modo aos valores dela serem usados ao invés da contagem. E usar `stat_summary_hex` ao invés de `geom_hex`, de modo a usar uma função agregadora mais adequada para os dados: `ggplot(df, aes(x, y, z = z)) + stat_summary_hex(fun = "sum") + facet_wrap(~cor)`